# Scoping through embedded document in MongoId

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, mongodb

I'm using MongoId in a Rails project. I need to select some products which contain some SKUs which has an embedded document. The models are respectively `Product` and `Sku`.

The point is I want to keep it DRY and the conditions I apply to those subdocument already exist as a scope of the model. My working strategy so far is to fetch all the skus of each products, apply the SKU scope and return an array of ids. Then, I just use this array to get the correct products.

```
  # in models/product.rb
  scope :has_available_sku, -> do
    skus_ids = self.all.reduce([]) do |acc, product|
        acc << product.available_skus.map(&:id)
    end.flatten
    self.where("skus._id" => {"$in" => skus_ids})
  end

  def available_skus
    skus.is_active.in_stock.order_by({:discount => :desc}, {:quantity => :desc})
  end

  # in models/sku.rb
  scope :is_active, -> { where(:status      => true) }
  scope :in_stock,  -> { any_of({:unlimited => true  }, {:quantity.gt => 0}) }
```

As you can see, if the scopes in the sku model change at some point, or even in the product model, the `has_available_sku` will still work because the MongoDB logic is contained in only area.

I could have queried another way and just put all the conditions in the `has_available_sku` scope and use things like `where("skus.status" => true)` but it's hardly maintainable.

Is my strategy valid or is it a bad idea to do this way? Is there any magic method I'm not aware of in MongoId which would make this more simple? Finally, is the second solution (not DRY) a better way to go?

**NOTE:** If you're curious and don't know, SKUs are basically the different subtype of a product, like an XXL and XL version of a t-shirt.

Comment: As far as I understood things correctly, you can build indexes on embedded documents so `where("skus.status" => true)` can be really fast whether the approach you suggested iterates on the whole DB to find products with available SKUs. Ok for a small DB but what about big ones ??

Comment: If you ever come up with something better please answer your question I am also interested.

Comment: That's very old question I asked, but basically I still use loops such as what I did, in a cleaner way, with Mongo to this day.